# Create a new column in Pandas Data-frame with a string value of a mask

Tags: python, pandas

i'm trying to add a new column into my data frame that specifies if a user in the "created by" column is part of a team(which is held in a separate list).

Original Data frame(df)

```
                 URL      text  created_by
id
1    www.pandora.com   Pandora  John
2     m.jcpenney.com     other  Steve
3    www.youtube.com   You-tube Rob
4   www.facebook.com  Facebook  David
Team_Names = ['John','Steve','Rob','Euan']
```

I want the final data frame to contain a new column with True or False values depending on if the "created by" value is in the "Tam_Names" list

```
Team_Mask = df['Created by'].isin(Team_Names)
df['In_Team'] = df.[Team_Mask]
```

i'm getting errors on the last line of code.Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Assign mask to new column:

```
Team_Names = ['John','Steve','Rob','Euan']
df['In_Team'] = df['created_by'].isin(Team_Names)
print (df)
                URL      text created_by  In_Team
1   www.pandora.com   Pandora       John     True
2    m.jcpenney.com     other      Steve     True
3   www.youtube.com  You-tube        Rob     True
4  www.facebook.com  Facebook      David    False
```

Or use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(In_Team = df['created_by'].isin(Team_Names))
```

Comment: @GottiJay - yes, I was curious with another solution, so add comment. Btw, `str.contains` is good solution, if need check subtrings, here for check strings is better isin.

Comment: Agreed, here `.ìsin` is the best approach +1